# article:publisher meta tag cannot be parsed as profile

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

According to this update... 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/19/platform-updates--new-open-graph-tags-for-media-publishers-and-more/

...I thought article:publisher (with page ID or URL) would put a like button for the representative page when shared links are posted to walls? The debugger seems to think differently... what am I missing?

Debugger info:

```
Object at URL 'http:// domain.com/post/' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value 'http:// www.facebook.com/mypage' for property 'article:publisher' could not be parsed as type 'profile'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`article:publisher` is for Facebook pages, `article:author` is for individuals.

The "Follow" and "Like" buttons will only appear for people who haven't already followed the author or liked the publisher page.