# I set og:type with 'article' but why og type always show on default 'website'

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with og: type facebook. i already set meta og: type to 'article', but still detected og: type it is 'website'.
However, everytime I try to scrape again, og: type changes to 'article'. So, there's no way I should do manual scrape every time a post.

This is my code:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="https://jpnn.dev/news/pdip-usung-jenderal-berbadan-besar-jadi-cagub-maluku"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="PDIP Usung Jenderal Berbadan Besar jadi Cagub Maluku"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Bu Megawati bercanda, menyebut sang jenderal sedang cari kerjaan karena sudah mau pensiun."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://photo.jpnn.com/arsip/normal/2017/05/21/25841e2eda0d3bbe198b1f9e6662a8c0.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="250" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="id_ID"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="www.jpnn.com"/>
<meta property="og:ttl" content="345600"/>
<meta name="Facebot" content="index,follow" />
<meta name="pubdate" content="2017-12-17T14-22-00Z" itemprop="datePublished" />
<meta content="2017-12-17T14-22-00Z" itemprop="dateCreated" />
<meta property="article:author" content="53788620694"/>
<meta property="article:publisher" content="53788620694"/>
<meta property="article:section" content="politik"/>
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2017-12-17T14-22-00Z"/>
<meta property="article:tag" content="Murad Ismail"/>
<meta property="article:tag" content="Pilgub Maluku 2018"/>
<meta property="article:tag" content="PDIP"/>
```

And this is the result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZF9q.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP7JY.png)

What's wrong with my code ?
Help me please :(

Thx

Comment: Seems to pick it up fine now, all it needed was a re-scrape: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jpnn.com%2Fnews%2Fpdip-usung-jenderal-berbadan-besar-jadi-cagub-maluku

Comment: yes, but i am not possible to do manual scrape again on every post. so what makes facebook does not detect og: type article when their robot begins scraping ?

Comment: I have exactly the same behavior, any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly the same behavior (2)

Answer (score 1):

The type of `article:author` is `profile`, not `string`.

Which, means the value must be a URL to a web page with Open Graph `profile` markups (like a Facebook profile page, but not necessarily Facebook.).

Answer (score 0):

I used https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and it showed me an alert like this:

> Object at URL 'http://example.com/post/' of type 'article' is invalid
>   because the given value 'Your awesome name' for property
>   'article:author' could not be parsed as type 'profile'.

Then I found [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24411779/1657502):

> `article:publisher` is for Facebook pages, `article:author` is for
>   individuals.

Whose question points to [this Facebook blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/19/platform-updates--new-open-graph-tags-for-media-publishers-and-more/) (from 2013/06/19):

> Today we're introducing updates to two tags:
>
> - `article:publisher` lets a publisher link an article to their own
>     Facebook page. When the article is shared in News Feed, a "like"
>     button is displayed so people can like the publisher page.

```
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/cnn" />
```

> - `article:author` lets a publisher link an article to the Facebook
>     profile of the author. When the article is shared in News Feed, a
>     "follow" button is displayed so people can follow the author. The
>     author needs to have Follow activated on his or her profile for this
>     button to appear.

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/fareedzakaria" />
```

In your case, I believe you should replace:

```
<meta property="article:author" content="53788620694"/>
<meta property="article:publisher" content="53788620694"/>
```

by:

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/gilang.sonar"/>
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/jpnncom/"/>
```

Comment: Values of the `profile` type may be some other than a URL to a Facebook profile page.